# Deploy job throw "react-router"' has no exported member 'PartialRouteObject

Tags: reactjs, github, gitlab-ci

I am trying to deploy the React project via Github CI/CD to Azure Static WebApp. However, Github throws build error non visible on my local installation. I have tried `yarn run build and yarn run` locally without any issue, but the Github keep complaining with the following error `Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'PartialRouteObject'.  TS2305` on the line:

```
import { PartialRouteObject } from 'react-router';
```

The package.js has this reference `"react-router-dom": "6.0.0-beta.0",` Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue when I upgraded `react-router-dom` to version 6. I fixed this issue by replacing `PartialRouteObject` with `RouteObject`.

```js
import { RouteObject } from 'react-router';
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with `"react-router-dom": "6.0.0-beta.0"` and after researching, I found the hint in `node_modules/react-router/README.md`.

```markdown
If you're using React Router, you should never `import` anything directly from
the `react-router` package, but you should have everything you need in either
`react-router-dom` or `react-router-native`. Both of those packages re-export
everything from `react-router`.

If you'd like to extend React Router and you know what you're doing, you should
add `react-router` **as a peer dependency, not a regular dependency** in your
package.
```

thus I did add to `package.json`

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-router": "6.0.0-beta.0"
  },
```

and run `npm i` from the terminal to make the change effective.

You may also need to disable eslint as it still complains in my case and fail the CI/CD pipeline.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/named
import {PartialRouteObject} from 'react-router'
```

At the time of writing, it's worth noting that you may upgrade to the latest version of `react-router v6.3` and get away with this issue. But in our case, we can't since there are a few features working in v6.0.0-beta.0 that v6.3 can't still deliver, such as https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139

Hope it helps. Happy coding!